# EXtract data with SCrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a beginner in python and scrapy.
I need  help, I  extracted datas  from defferents sales sites computers.
I need the brand or marks  of the computer, the problem  the marks in the sites are images 
my code:

```
marks = hxs.select('//*[@id="produit_liste_marque"]/a/img/@src').extract()
```

I need to convert picture to  text for example :

```
<img src="http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/3/small/Lenovo.jpg" alt="Lenovo" title="Lenovo" border="0">
```

to lenovo

or there is a method to extract the title of the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `@attribute` to get attributes from a tag.

In this case `marks = hxs.select('//*[@id="produit_liste_marque"]/a/img/@title').extract()`